# Reading from 315MHz / 433MHz Rf reader module with Raspberry Pi GPIO

Tags: module, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2, gpio

OK, so I have a 3 pin 315/433MHz rf reader module which I've connected to my raspberry pi 2. 2 pins are for Voltage and ground, and 3rd goes to a GPIO pin configured as input.

I've actually gotten all of this to work just fine. I can read data manually from the GPIO pin just fine, by accessing the file

```
/sys/class/gpio/gpio23/value
```

I can even place a car key next to the receiver press a button, and see the values change between 0 and 1.

**The problem is that I cannot figure out how to read the clock, so I cannot figure out if there are supposed to be multiple ones or zeros in a row in the data its reading. There doesn't seem to be any time stamp that I can find to see when the last value was read.**

How can I properly read the data the module is receiving?

Answer (score 1):

There are two common protocols used for 315/434 MHz radio transmission by hobbyists (that I know of).

Keyfob type remote control devices tend to use Manchester Encoding.

General data transmission using the Virtual Wire protocol (as popular with Arduinos).

My pigpio library has a [Python](http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python_vw) Virtual Wire implementation and [C](http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#pdif2__433D)/[Python](http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python__433_py) keyfob Manchester Encoding example (for receive and transmit).

Answer (score 0):

your RF reader should be outputting serial data at some known baud rate (check the manual?) assuming you haven't wired it up to the dedicated serial pins you could look at using the pigpio library, more specifically the bit banging serial commands [here for python](http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html#bb_serial_read_open) or [here for C/C++](http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/cif.html#gpioSerialReadOpen) or [here for pipes](http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/pigs.html#SLRO)

This allows you to use any GPIO pin for reading serial data and the library has bindings for several methods of use as shown in the links above.